# How to make equal set of data with php

Tags: php, mysql

I have two data sets

One:

```
 2013-09-30   -31.10775
 2013-10-01   -9.19418
 2013-10-02   26.00109
 2013-10-03   -6.04632
 2013-10-06  -66.11115
 2013-10-07  -25.07811
 2013-10-08  -64.89727
 2013-10-09  29.21063
 2013-10-10  21.98792
 2013-10-20  -71.87298
 2013-10-21  -7.79364
 2013-10-22  50.77988
```

and

```
 2013-09-30      0.00
 2013-10-07      10.00
 2013-10-10      0.00
 2013-10-21     -5.50
 2013-10-22      25.60
```

what i want to achieve compare date of first set with second set date if matched then return second set price data else return the last data till it match form the next. i need this because to calculate covariance of those two price data how can i achieve that?

This is what I've try

```
SELECT IDX_DEVIATION
    ,IDX_DATE_TIME
FROM idx
WHERE IDX_DATE_TIME >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH)
ORDER BY IDX_DATE_TIME ASC;
```

for the first query and

```
SELECT (ltp-ycp) AS changes
    ,entry_date
FROM eod_stock
WHERE entry_date >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH)
    AND company_id = 2 ORDER by entry_date ASC;
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Where is the data stored?  How have you loaded it into memory?

Comment: these are returned data from mysql query as the query is irrelevant i did not post that, i just need php to match and equalize data.

Comment: Is your data stored in arrays then?

Comment: you can see the first data set has all date but sencond has not so i want to match date wise if second set dont have that data just take the previous price that has till next match is that clear? thanks for helping though

Comment: yes its stored in array

Comment: SELECT
IDX_DEVIATION,
IDX_DATE_TIME
FROM idx 
WHERE IDX_DATE_TIME  >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH)
ORDER by IDX_DATE_TIME ASC; for the first query  and

SELECT
(ltp-ycp) AS changes,
entry_date
FROM eod_stock
WHERE entry_date  >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH)
AND company_id = 2
ORDER by entry_date ASC; for the second if you need

Comment: can anyone help?? im stuck